# How to create tabs dynamically in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6, ios7

I am trying to implement the following kind of tabs into my Application. I have first tried it with creating buttons. So can anyone guide me how to create this kind of interface ?

[image]

I want to clarify that this are the groups & it will be dynamically created & it can be in any number.

Any suggestions & references will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been implementing pretty much exactly what you are asking in an app im working on, i've uploaded the source files [here](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/21753b05). its pretty much plug-and-play, just make a TabView where you want your tabs and hook up the delegate methods. can swap out all the images with your own (my tabs were underneath something and not on top so they will look upside down initially for you).

Dont really have time to explain the inner workings of it all, but if you play around with the code im sure you will manage to customise it how you want. otherwise, just learn from it and implement your own.

edit: oh and there is some code that changes how the tabs look depending if iOS 7 or not, you will get an error when first importing it because i have a variable in my appDelegate `isIOS7` which you can either implement in your app, or just take out all the relevant iOS 7 checks in the code